# Pandas - efficiently groupby over each column separately

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dask

I need to groupby each column separately and groupby to figure out few metrics.
Assume I have a bunch of feature columns and a binary target column. Each of the feature is a bin (a string). Target is an integer column. Here, just 1's and 0's for simplicity.

Example

```
import pandas as pd


var1 = ['var1_bin1', 'var1_bin2', 'var1_bin2', 'var1_bin3', 'var1_bin4', 'var1_bin4', 'var1_bin4', 'var1_bin5', 'var1_bin5', 'var1_bin5']
var2 = ['var2_bin1', 'var2_bin1', 'var2_bin2', 'var2_bin3', 'var2_bin3', 'var2_bin4', 'var2_bin4', 'var2_bin5', 'var2_bin5', 'var2_bin5']
var3 = ['var3_bin2', 'var3_bin2', 'var3_bin2', 'var3_bin3', 'var3_bin3', 'var3_bin3', 'var3_bin3', 'var3_bin4', 'var3_bin5', 'var3_bin5']
var4 = ['var4_bin1', 'var4_bin1', 'var4_bin2', 'var4_bin2', 'var4_bin4', 'var4_bin4', 'var4_bin4', 'var4_bin4', 'var4_bin4', 'var4_bin4']
target = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var1' : var1,
    'var2' : var2,
    'var3' : var3,
    'target' : target
})

print(df)
cols = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'target']

# need groupby for each column separately:
#  For each column, I want to group by categorical elements in column and sum elements from target variable and also count how many zeros are there

for col in cols:
    x = df.groupby([col, target])[[target]].sum() #expecting aggregated metrics
    print(x)
```

What I am expecting, the result as a dataframe of dataframes (or any better way) which visually I can communicate to you as follows:

```
Result representation
        var1                     | var2 ...
    ---------------------------- |
    bin    | sum | total_zeros   |
      -----------------          |
var1_bin1  | 1   | 0             |
var1_bin2  | 0   | 2             |
var1_bin3  | 1   | 0             |
var1_bin4  | 2   | 1             |
var1_bin5  | 0   | 3             |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*pandas answer*

We can achieve this by first iterating over all columns with `for col in df.columns`, using [`DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html)

Then we `GroupBy` on these columns and use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html). In this aggregation we take the `sum` of target and the `total zeros`.

Finally we use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat the each group next to each other.

```
dfg = pd.concat([
    (df.groupby(col)['target']
       .agg([(f'sum_{col}', 'sum'),(f'total_zeros_{col}', lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())])
       .reset_index()
    ) for col in df.columns
], axis=1)
```

```
        var1  sum_var1  total_zeros_var1       var2  sum_var2  total_zeros_var2       var3  sum_var3  total_zeros_var3       var4  sum_var4  total_zeros_var4  target  sum_target  total_zeros_target
0  var1_bin1         1                 0  var2_bin1         1                 1  var3_bin2      1.00              2.00  var4_bin1      1.00              1.00    0.00        0.00                6.00
1  var1_bin2         0                 2  var2_bin2         0                 1  var3_bin3      3.00              1.00  var4_bin2      1.00              1.00    1.00        4.00                0.00
2  var1_bin3         1                 0  var2_bin3         2                 0  var3_bin4      0.00              1.00  var4_bin4      2.00              4.00     nan         nan                 nan
3  var1_bin4         2                 1  var2_bin4         1                 1  var3_bin5      0.00              2.00        NaN       nan               nan     nan         nan                 nan
4  var1_bin5         0                 3  var2_bin5         0                 3        NaN       nan               nan        NaN       nan               nan     nan         nan                 nan
```

Comment: This was a pandas answer, added it to top of answer, good point @jezrael

Comment: I see, but in this example it only shows `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: I am eventually using dask, should have asked for both pandas and dask. My bad!

Comment: OK, no problem, answer was created.

Answer (score 0):

Because performance is important count `0` values before `groupby`, not per groups, so for count is possible aggregate `sum` of both columns:

```
df1 = pd.concat([
    (df.assign(total_zeros = df[col].eq(0).astype(int))
       .groupby(col)['target','total_zeros']
       .sum()
       .add_suffix(f'_{col}')
       .reset_index()
    ) for col in df.columns
], axis=1)

print(df1)
        var1  target_var1  total_zeros_var1       var2  target_var2  \
0  var1_bin1            1                 0  var2_bin1            1   
1  var1_bin2            0                 0  var2_bin2            0   
2  var1_bin3            1                 0  var2_bin3            2   
3  var1_bin4            2                 0  var2_bin4            1   
4  var1_bin5            0                 0  var2_bin5            0   

   total_zeros_var2       var3  target_var3  total_zeros_var3  target  \
0                 0  var3_bin2          1.0               0.0     0.0   
1                 0  var3_bin3          3.0               0.0     1.0   
2                 0  var3_bin4          0.0               0.0     NaN   
3                 0  var3_bin5          0.0               0.0     NaN   
4                 0        NaN          NaN               NaN     NaN   

   target_target  total_zeros_target  
0            0.0                 6.0  
1            4.0                 0.0  
2            NaN                 NaN  
3            NaN                 NaN  
4            NaN                 NaN
```